# Flat Binary format

Tags: assembly, binary

I am a bit confused about bin formats, I am using the nasm assembler and I don't quite understand how segements and BBS values are enocoded into BIN. How is this format loaded by the system when executed?

Many thanks

Comment: Isn't the purpose of a flat binary format not to have any of that and avoid the link-load steps altogether? I think execution just starts at byte `0` of the binary and you are on your own from there.

Comment: Yes, I realize it's something like that. But I'm just wondering how different segments are placed, and if BSS sections are actually filled with zeros in the bin file.

Answer (score 3):

`bin` does not retain any structure nor segments. All code and data goes as is, there are no special headers or descriptors. .bss contents are ignored for `bin` and resb/resw/resd/etc should be used as placeholder.

Sample code:

```
bits 16
section .text
org 100h

; copy hw[] to copy[]
mov si, hw
mov di, copy
mov cx, 15
cld
rep movsb

; print copy[]
mov dx, copy
mov ah, 9
int 21h
ret

section .bss

blah db "0123456789abcdef" ; data will be ignored, nasm will warn here

copy resb 15 ; reserve 15 bytes for the text string

section .data

hw db "Hello Wrold!",13,10,"$"
```

Compiling:

```
C:\>nasm nsm.asm -fbin -onsm.com
nsm.asm:20: warning: attempt to initialise memory in a nobits section: ignored
```

Disassemblying:

```
C:\>ndisasm -b 16 -o 100h nsm.com
00000100  BE1401            mov si,0x114
00000103  BF3401            mov di,0x134
00000106  B90F00            mov cx,0xf
00000109  FC                cld
0000010A  F3A4              rep movsb
0000010C  BA3401            mov dx,0x134
0000010F  B409              mov ah,0x9
00000111  CD21              int 0x21
00000113  C3                ret
00000114  48                dec ax ; this is hw db "Hello Wrold!",13,10,"$"
00000115  656C              gs insb
00000117  6C                insb
00000118  6F                outsw
00000119  205772            and [bx+0x72],dl
0000011C  6F                outsw
0000011D  6C                insb
0000011E  64210D            and [fs:di],cx
00000121  0A24              or ah,[si]
```

Running on Windows XP (or DOS):

```
C:\>nsm.com
Hello Wrold!
```

It is expected by the OS that DOS .COM-style programs have no special structure and the very first byte of the file contains the first instruction that has to be executed.

Please see the NASM documentation for details. I believe you can find all answers to your questions there.

Comment: Thank you! This really cleared things up. But does this mean with BIN the segment register is purely for addressing (real mode?) and not for segment control (protected mode)?

Comment: @user982401: Nasm's sections/segments in the binary format are practically useless, you can have them in the source file, but there's barely a trace of them in the output binary. If you assemble the source file into some other output format, e.g. obj, coff/aout, elf, win32 then the sections/segments will make it into the output file and the linker will be able to do some meaningful work with them (create a proper executable file for the OS with pieces of it marked as code (executable), data (non-executable), etc). Only in the obj format sections/segments represent x86 segments.

Comment: @user: on real mode segments are only used for addresing, they are actually a hack to allow access to 1MB in a 16bit machine, which would otherwise only have access to 64KB.